# Solve the following constrained maximization problem

Tags: derivatives, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Question: let $T\geq$ 1 be some finite integer, solve the following maximization problem.

Maximize $\sum_{t=1}^T$($\frac{1}{2}$)$^t$$\sqrt{x_t}$ subject to $\sum_{t=1}^{T}$$x_t\leq1$, $x_t\geq0$, t=1,...,T

I have never had to maximize summations before and I do not know how to do so. Can someone show me a step by step break down of the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the method of Lagrange Multipliers.

Denote your objective function by $f(x) = \sum_{t=1}^T(\frac{1}{2})^t\sqrt{x_t}$.

Since your constraint is on the sum of the x variables, an optimal solution $x^*$ will have a gradient which is parallel to the vector $(1,1,\ldots,1)$, i.e. We seek a point where $\nabla f(x^*) = \lambda (1,1,\ldots,1)$.

Computing the gradient of $f$, we get $(\frac{1}{4\sqrt{x_1}}, \frac{1}{8\sqrt{x_2}}, \ldots,\frac{1}{2^{T+1}\sqrt{x_T}}).$

Solve for which $x^*$ causes the gradient to have all its coordinates equal. In other words, find values for $x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_T$ so that
$$\frac{1}{4\sqrt{x_1}} = \frac{1}{8\sqrt{x_2}} = \ldots = \frac{1}{2^{T+1}\sqrt{x_T}}$$
Then you will have your optimal solution.

Comment: What is my objective function then? Does it include the sum notation symbol as well?

Comment: Moreover, I don’t follow the last portion of the problem. How do I get all of my “gradients” ( a term I am not familiar with) equal to one another?

Comment: The objective function is the function you are trying to maximize, so yes it is a sum. Ill modify the answer. 
By gradient I just mean the derivative. But since the function has several variables, it is not just a real number but a vector.

Comment: That makes a bit more sense, but it is still a bit unclear. So I take the derivative(s) which you show in the “computing the gradient of f,...’ portion, and then I need to solve and find a real number? Becuase if I do that (using 1 as my x value(s)) I get 1/4, 1/8 etc.

Comment: You've almost got it. You need to pick a (possibly different) real number for each of the $x_i$'s so that each coordinate is the same. I will clarify in the answer

Comment: How can I best choose the real numbers? Is there any special formula or the like?

Comment: Perhaps setting all of the individual term to zero could work, but I am unsure.

Comment: I've reduced the problem to some simple algebraic manipulations. To start with, try answering when does $1/4x_1 = 1/8x_2$.

Comment: $2x_1=x_2$ is the answer I am getting

Comment: If it was helpful you can mark my answer as accepted

Comment: How do I do that? I am still relatively new to this website.

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{t=1}^T 2^{-t}\sqrt{x_t} &\le \sqrt{\left(\sum_{t=1}^T 2^{-2t}\right)\left(\sum_{t=1}^T x_t\right)}\\
&\le \sqrt{\sum_{t=1}^T 2^{-2t}}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{1-4^{-n}}{3}}
\end{align}
with equality if $\sum_{t=1}^T x_t = 1$ and $\frac{\sqrt{x_1}}{2^{-1}} = \frac{\sqrt{x_2}}{2^{-2}} = \cdots = \frac{\sqrt{x_n}}{2^{-n}}$.

Thus, the maximum of $\sum_{t=1}^T 2^{-t}\sqrt{x_t}$ is $\sqrt{\frac{1-4^{-n}}{3}}$
achieved at $x_i = \frac{3}{1-4^{-n}}\cdot 2^{-2i}, \ i=1, 2, \cdots, n$.